# Google MX and Zoho MX records for a single domain

Tags: gmail, zoho, mx-record

I have been using Google mail application. I have created one email address in Google Mail. 
I need to add some more email address and Google is very expensive to create emails. So I am planing to use Zoho for others emails. For example, I created info@example.com in Google application and I want to created santosh@example.com in zoho.
Is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you might thought about to setup two MX record (one from Zoho and another one from Google Apps) with different priority could work, but it won't work like that. Single mail server MX can be set as default. You can set two different MX record but that would work as fail-over, it can't split your delivery.

Yes it is possible, the technology called Dual Delivery OR Split Delivery.  When emails are addressed to email addresses that are not found in one mail server it will send its delivery to another mail server and even can split them.

**For example**
domain.com has default mx record set to Zoho. User abc@domain.com is set under google apps & user xyz@domain.com under Zoho. Now if someone send mail to abc@domain.com which is configured under google apps, so the first request transferred to Zoho but zoho cannot found that email within organization so it will push the request to Google apps and will deliver the mail in its inbox.

Google Apps also offer dual delivery but unfortunately its available for Google Apps for Work account only. Zoho is offering it for all type of accounts so you still have chance to get it done via zoho.

**Solution**

1. Set up your domain MX record to Zoho
2. Configure delivery as per guideline mentioned here

https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/email-routing.html

If you would like to keep google apps account as primary then setup instructions can be found here https://support.google.com/a/answer/96855?hl=en